# D exit statement

Tags: d, exit

Does D have an exit statement, similar to the one in java, python, c/c++. Which will (big shocker) exit execution of the program? Something like `exit();`

Comment: If I recall well, D supports the C standard library which contains exit().

Comment: Yes, but if possible I would like to keep to D only, maybe I could throw an exception, catch it, and that would exit just as well.

Comment: That would probably be a better way to handle it. Normally, you want to exit via `main` rather than an arbitrary place in the program like would happen with `exit`. It leads to better error handling and makes it easier to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want `exit`, then use C's `exit` function.

```
import core.stdc.stdlib;

void main()
{
    exit(-1);
}
```

I'm not quite sure how that affects the D runtime and whatnot though. It might be that stuff doesn't get cleaned up like you'd normally want, or it might be just fine. I wouldn't really advise using it in general though, since there are usually better ways to handle exiting a program. But the declaration for the C function is in druntime, so it's easy to use it if you want it.

Comment: it's good to know that the D community is growing! Just visited the new website and was surprised to releases recently.

Comment: Releases occur fairly regularly, but when we moved the code to github, it really improved the level of community involvement in the development of the compiler and the standard library. And a _ton_ of bugs have been getting fixed with the recent releases.

Comment: It's on github? Maybe Someone can add an exit statement.

Comment: They're not going to add an `exit` function when C already has one. What would it do anyway other than call the C function? Throw an exception? You can do that yourself without an extra function call. Just throw it. And if a D `exit` function didn't do what the C function does, it would just confuse people who are familiar with the C function. If you want `exit`, then use C's `exit`. If you want to use an exception and catch that in main, then do that. They're two totally different approaches.