# D: How to exit from main?

Tags: d, program-entry-point, exit

What it the D way to terminate/exit main function?

```
import std.stdio;
import core.thread;

void main()
{
    int i;
    while (i <= 5)
    {
        writeln(i++);
        core.thread.Thread.sleep( dur!("seconds")(1) );
    }
    if (i == 5) 
    {
        writeln("Exit");
        return; // I need terminate main, but it's look like break do exit only from scope
    }
    readln(); // it's still wait a user input, but I need exit from App in previous step
}
```

I tried to googling and found next question [D exit statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099956/d-exit-statement)
there is suggestion to use C exit function. Is there any new futures in modern D, that are allow to do it's more elegant?

Comment: The return statement in your code will exit the program. The problem you have is one of logic - when the while loop terminates, i == 6, not 5.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe, oh, you are right, is there any way to fix it in while loop, or only possible fix is `if (i == 6) `?

Comment: As Adam has stated the `if (i == 5)` is always false. You can write `if (i == 6)` if you want to execute the `if` branch. Or did you intend to have the `if` inside the loop? The use of the post-increment operator change the output of your program but it still exits the loop with `i == 6`.

Comment: thanks! Is it's correct to exit from main with `return`? what difference between exiting with `exit(0);`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `return` to exit from `main`. If you define main with `int main(string[] args)` then you can also set the return code. `exit(0)` terminates the process and does not run destructors, finalizers and so on. This may result in some garbage. This does not happen if you use `return` in the main function.

Comment: As shown in the answer below, you can use "int main()" instead of "void main()" and then use the return statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import stdlib and call exit while passing 0.

```
 import std.c.stdlib;
    exit(0);
```

Comment: That doesn't run finalizers though.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not doing an emergency exit then you want to clean up everything. I created an `ExitException` for this purpose:

```
class ExitException : Exception
{
    int rc;

    @safe pure nothrow this(int rc, string file = __FILE__, size_t line = __LINE__)
    {
        super(null, file, line);
        this.rc = rc;
    }
}
```

You code your `main()` function then like

```
int main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        // Your code here
    }
    catch (ExitException e)
    {
        return e.rc;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At the point where you need to exit you call

```
throw new ExitException(1);
```